# R how do I retain string between two indetifiers

Tags: r, text, substring

I have a column with lot of text, I just want to retain text that are between [`start section id="20107"]` and `[end section id="20107"]` rest are not important.

Here the original data

```
[start section id="20106"]

California, Death Valley 

[end section id="20106"]

[start section id="20107"]

1. Apple
2. Orange
3. Bannana
4. Kiwi
5. Grapes
6. Strawberry

[end section id="20107"]


[start section id="20108"]

Jose has worked on these farms , currently he is in Florida picking tomatos

[end section id="20108"]
```

What I am trying to do is just retain text between start section id="20107" and end section id="20107"

```
[start section id="20107"]

1. Apple
2. Orange
3. Bannana
4. Kiwi
5. Grapes
6. Strawberry

[end section id="20107"]
```

Any help on this topic is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Here's how to create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Heroka, I have tried `testdf = filter(org_df, grepl('[start section id="20107"]|[end section id="20107"]', col1))` , i am not getting the right results, it shows the original column and does not get rid of text outside these start and end conditons

Comment: Please provide some sample data and add what you've tried to your answer. And grepl returns a string of booleans for a match inside the entire string. You might need gsub.

Comment: @Heroka, cool , did  that

Comment: Your code example is not in typical R syntax. Use `dput(mydata)` to post the actual code instead of an interpretive text copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `sub`

```
x <- '[start section id="20107"]

1. Apple
2. Orange
3. Bannana
4. Kiwi
5. Grapes
6. Strawberry

[end section id="20107"]


[start section id="20108"]

Jose has worked on these farms , currently he is in Florida picking tomatos

[end section id="20108"]'
cat(sub('[\\s\\S]*(\\[start section id="20107"\\][\\s\\S]*?\\[end section id="20107"\\])[\\s\\S]*', '\\1', x, perl=T))

#[start section id="20107"]

#1. Apple
#2. Orange
#3. Bannana
#4. Kiwi
#5. Grapes
#6. Strawberry

#[end section id="20107"]
```

Comment: that did not filter text between the start and end point, it just showed the same column, same as before, no change

Comment: did you run my code? May be it's because of the spaces in my regex , use `\\s+` instead of spaces in my regex.